# cluster presentation dendrogram alternative in r

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, phylogeny

I know dendrograms are quite popular. However if there are quite large number of observations and classes it hard to follow. However sometime I feel that there should be better way to present the same thing. I got an idea but do not know how to implement it.

Consider the following dendrogram.

```
> data(mtcars)
> plot(hclust(dist(mtcars)))
```

[image]

Can plot it like a scatter plot. In which the distance between two points is plotted with line, while sperate clusters (assumed threshold) are colored and circle size is determined by value of some variable.

[image]

Comment: the igraph package is what you're after

Comment: You can use some form of multidimensional scaling (`cmdscale`) to find the coordinates, then draw the tree returned by `hclust`, and use `cut` to determine the node colours.

Comment: I do not know actual math of it, but just plotting part may be the package qgraph be helpful... https://sites.google.com/site/qgraphproject/examples

Comment: Is subsetting the dendrogram an option? Using a network graph you hide some information about hierarchy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are describing a fairly typical way of going about cluster analysis:

- Use a clustering algorithm (in this case hierarchical clustering)
- Decide on the number of clusters
- Project the data in a two-dimensional plane using some form or principal component analysis

The code:

```
hc <- hclust(dist(mtcars))
cluster <- cutree(hc, k=3)
xy <- data.frame(cmdscale(dist(mtcars)), factor(cluster))
names(xy) <- c("x", "y", "cluster")
xy$model <- rownames(xy)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(xy, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(aes(colour=cluster), size=3)
```

What happens next is that you get a skilled statistician to help explain what the x and y axes mean. This usually involves projecting the data to the axes and extracting the factor loadings.

The plot:

[image]

Comment: many thanks Andrie, is there is way to connect all points( if possible perhaps with same color within same cluster while different color as gray for inter clusters)